# Shopify GraphQL Get Schema from Server

Tags: json, shopify, graphql

I am using `graphql-js-schema-fetch` to fetch Shopify schema, but it throws an error and I do not know how to fix it.

Using CLI:

```
graphql-js-schema-fetch https://myspati-com.myshopify.com/api/graphql --header "Content-Type: application/graphql" --header "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token: <acces-token>"
```

This is the error:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "message": "Parse error on \"query\" (STRING) at [1, 2]",
        "locations": [{
            "line": 1,
            "column": 2
        }]
    }]
}
```

Anyone with experience here?

Answer (score 20):

Try changing the `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

This works for me despite all the docs saying to use `application/graphql`

Comment: I was having the same error with Postman and passing `application/json` solved, but must be a "problem" of the client, a PHP API I'm using send `json` for mutations and `graphql` for queries, both working.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for me was:

```sh
apollo service:download types/download.json --endpoint=https://{your-shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/graphql.json --header="X-Shopify-Access-Token: <admin-access-token>"
```

> PS: Change the `2022-04` to the latest API version.

If you want the download file into a SDL format instead of JSON use this approach:

```sh
apollo client:download-schema types/download.graphql --endpoint=https://{your-shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/graphql.json --header="X-Shopify-Access-Token: <admin-access-token>"
```

Apollo client will conside the output as a SDL format:

```
"""
Returns unfulfilled line items grouped by their fulfillment service. Each draft fulfillment contains additional information, such as whether the fulfillment requires shipping and whether a shipping label can be printed for it.
"""
type DraftFulfillment {
  """Whether a label can be purchased."""
  allowLabelPurchase: Boolean!

  """
  The line items (which might correspond to a variant) that are part of this draft fulfillment.
  """
  lineItems: [LineItem!]!

  """Whether a fulfillment requires shipping."""
  requiresShipping: Boolean!

  """The service responsible for fulfilling the fulfillment."""
  service: FulfillmentService!
}
```

Comment: You are a legend! Latest API version changed to `2023-04`

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove "Content-Type" and Access-Token and replace it with the Shopifys credentials. Now it works for me.

```
graphql-js-schema-fetch --url 'https://graphql.myshopify.com/api/graphql' --header 'Authorization: Basic MzUxYzEyMjAxN2QwZjJhOTU3ZDMyYWU3MjhhZDc0OWM=' | jq '.' > shopify-schema.json
```